# Panopto API - How to pass parameters for Pagination (SessionManagement)?

Tags: php, soap, pagination

I am using PHP 5.5.9, I have created an object parameter for pagination GetSessionList and set MaxNumberResults to 100 but still get  25 session in GetSessionList method? my total sessions are 627. below is my ListSessionRequest function to pass SOAP parameters. Can anyone help me, because I don't get any error in the code.

```
function Create_ListSessionsRequest_Object($endDate, $folderId, $remoteRecorderId, $sortBy, $sortIncreasing, $startDate) {

    //Create empty object to store member data
    $listSessionsRequest = new stdClass();

    $listSessionsRequest->EndDate = new SoapVar($endDate, XSD_STRING, null, null, null, PanoptoSessionManagementSoapClient::OBJECT_MEMBER_NAMESPACE);

    $listSessionsRequest->FolderId = '<ns:FolderId xmlns:field="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" FolderId:nil="true" />';

    $listSessionsRequest->RemoteRecorderId = '<ns:RemoteRecorderId xmlns:field="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" RemoteRecorderId:nil="true" />';

    $listSessionsRequest->SortBy = new SoapVar($sortBy, XSD_STRING, null, null, null, PanoptoSessionManagementSoapClient::OBJECT_MEMBER_NAMESPACE);
    $listSessionsRequest->SortIncreasing = new SoapVar($sortIncreasing, XSD_BOOLEAN, null, null, null, PanoptoSessionManagementSoapClient::OBJECT_MEMBER_NAMESPACE);
    $listSessionsRequest->StartDate = new SoapVar($startDate, XSD_STRING, null, null, null, PanoptoSessionManagementSoapClient::OBJECT_MEMBER_NAMESPACE);

    $PaginationRequest = new stdClass();
    $PaginationRequest->MaxNumberResults = 100;
    $PaginationRequest->PageNumber = 1;

    $listSessionsRequest->Pagination = new SoapVar($PaginationRequest, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT , null, null, null, PanoptoSessionManagementSoapClient::OBJECT_MEMBER_NAMESPACE);

    echo var_dump($listSessionsRequest);
    echo "<br><br>";
    //exit;

    return $listSessionsRequest;
}
```

Comment: Been stuck on the same thing for ages ! Did you guys manage to find any solution for this ?